# Не выполняется проверка на пустую строку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу выполнить проверку и делаю условие:

```
var name = $(this).find('.some-div').text();
if(name){
  //do smth
}
```

По идее, действие внутри условного оператора if не должно выполняться, если в блоке `<div class="some-div"></div>` нет текста. Но в моём коде действие почему-то выполняется. Хотя в строке 0 символов. То есть, она пустая. Как мне правильно выполнить проверку строки на наличие символов?

**УТОЧНЯЮ ВОПРОС**

Есть код:

```
$('.card.offer .card-image').each(function() {
    var cityname = $(this).find('.iata-searcher').text();
    var that = $(this);
    if(cityname.length != 0){
        var requestURL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=dd7db2cb607c16d11c25c747acde0c06&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&sort=relevance&safe_search=1&per_page=1&text=' + cityname + '%20city';
        $.ajax({
            url: requestURL,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {
            var link = 'https://farm' + data.photos.photo[0].farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + data.photos.photo[0].server + '/' + data.photos.photo[0].id + '_' + data.photos.photo[0].secret + '.jpg';
            //console.log(link);
            that.find('img').attr('src', link);
        });
    } else {
        that.find('img').attr('src', '/img/no_image.png');
    }
});
```

И по идее, если cityname пуст, то то, что в теле условного оператора не должно выполняться вообще. Но отладчик жалуется, что `data.photos.photo[0].farm` undefined.

Comment: в проверяли в консоли браузер содержимое этой переменной?

Comment: А вы уверены, что `name.length` возвращает `0`?

Comment: По логике условие не должно отрабатывать. Попробуйте проверить, на что ссылается Ваш this.

Comment: "_**Хотя в строке 0 символов.**_" - именно так и проверьте.

Comment: .iata-searcher - что это? div? input?

Comment: `if(name.trim()) { `, желательно это делать на сервере тоже, чтобы таких казусов не было.

Answer (score 1):

Условие пройдет, если символов нет вообще. Если есть хотябы один пробел или перенос строки - то уже нет. В этом случае можно вырезать все пробелы с помощью `trim()`

```js
var name = $('.some-div').text();
if(name){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}

var name = $('.some-div2').text();
if(name){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
if(name.trim()){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-div"></div><div class="some-div2"> </div>
```

Comment: Добавил полный код, просмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score -2):

Для того, чтобы проверить наличие текста в элементе достаточно подключить jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">

if ($('.some-div').val()){
    //делаю что-то
}
```

или так

```
var element = $('.some-div').html();
if (element == ''){
    //делаю что-то
};
```

По поводу того, почему идет внутрь цикла:
Выведи в консоль console.log() или alert() что лежит внутри переменной которая является условием цикла, а там уже поймешь почему не пустое значение.

Comment: у объекта-обертки jQuery нет свойства `value`

Comment: Но есть `.val()`

Comment: Согласен, исправил.

Comment: Разве `val()` - свойство?

Comment: @Other это не свойство, а метод, который возвращает строку или массив строк, в зависимости от элемента над которым совершается действие.

Comment: @A.Piks - ну так вызывайте его. `if ($('.some-div').val)` - всегда `true`

Comment: метод `.val()` пременим к `input` и `textarea`, он может как вернуть так и добавить текст, при пустой строке отчистит поле. К `div` применим `text()` и `html()` - работающие аналогично, за исключением, что `text` не может содержать `html` кода.